# Azure Backup Server error: ID 4501

Tags: azure, scdpm

I'm trying to set up a backup Windows VMs to Azure using Azure Backup. I have successfully installed Azure Backup Server to Windows Server 2016 VM and configure VMware vSphere VMs backup using the manuals:

1. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-microsoft-azure-backup
2. https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/azure-offers-backing-up-vmware-vms-with-a-freeware-tool

I need to do the same thing for Windows VMs running on local Hyper-V 2016. 
Following the same guidance, I'm trying to deploy Azure Backup to Hyper-V 2016 host, and face the issue at 3rd stage (SQL Setting):

> There is something wrong with the scenarios or checks xml. (ID: 4501)
>
> Check the XMLs and try again
>
> More information

Nothing else appears in Event Log.

More information links to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3041338/data-protection-manager-error-codes
and there is no such ID.

**Where the XMLs are located?**

Hyper-V 2016 info if needed:

- Dell T420, E5-2509v3, 128GB RAM, 480GB SSD RAID1, 2,4GB HDD RAID 10.
- Hyper-V version: 10.0.14393.1378
- Installed roles and features: Hyper-V, SIS, .Net 3.5 and 4.6, MPIO.

Let me know if any additional information is required

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to completly reinstall The Single Instance Store (SIS) component

To uninstall Windows Single Instance Storage (SIS)
In an elevated command prompt window, run `start /w ocsetup.exe SIS-Limited /uninstall /quiet /norestart`.
After SIS is uninstalled, you must restart the computer.

To manually install Windows Single Instance Store (SIS)
On the computer that will be your DPM server, open an elevated command prompt window, type the following command, and then press ENTER.

```
start /wait ocsetup.exe SIS-Limited /quiet /norestart
```

or

```
start /wait dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featureName:SIS-Limited /quiet /norestart
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff399781.aspx

Comment: SIS was successfully reinstall using `start /wait dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featureName:SIS-Limited /quiet /norestart` so I could continue with the installation. Thanks.